# What were the cultures of peasants in China during the Hundred Schools period (600-221BCE)?

Tags: social-history, ancient-china, cultural-history, peasants

During the Hundred Schools period (600-221 BCE) Chinese cultures changed significantly as ideas were contested amongst the ruling elite.

What do we know of peasant cultures in China during this period?  What was their yearly economy?  Their diet?  Their marriage customs?  Their religions?  Do we have accounts of their lives and thoughts?  Do we have waste fragment texts explaining their culture?

What was the every day life of the ordinary person in China in this period, and which major sources support such an account?

Comment: I feel that each of those facets of culture you listed could/should be its own question... I want to write about the marriage customs, but it's gonna take me a while to finish.

Comment: I'll split this and leave this particular question as the question on marriage customs for @Semaphore answering.

Comment: It's kinda sad to stumble upon this exchange a few years later, and to see that nothing came of it ...